# How to solve Could not attach to main target error?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

Can't debug on Chrome under VS Code - getting "Could not attach to main target" error

Searches have given two approaches to fix, neither of which have helped:
Disabling javascript preview doesn't help.
Going back to earlier versions of Chrome doesn't help.

The error is sparse on detail:
[error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT7J1.png)

I CAN debug on Edge and Firefox, it's only Chrome that gives me this headache. The entries in launch.json for Chrome, Edge, and Firefox are all identical, with the exception of the "type" entry.

No one else seems to have run across this - any ideas to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest [nightly build](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/#nightly-extension) where this issue is fixed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32067584)